# Marking Badblocks and formatting external 1TB/2TB hard drives

Tags: linux, windows, macos, filesystems

What is most effective tools to mark badblock on large external 1TB/2TB hard drives.

Also how to format it in Fat 32 so these drives are most accessible on all OSs

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any decent recently made drive, which should include any 1-2T drive, will have SMART technology wherein the drive firmware itself remaps bad blocks to good ones transparently to the host. If you are able to detect bad blocks at all, the drive is already well into a failure regime as it has exhausted its reservation of bad block spares, and you should not use it. In short, don't worry about bad block scanning.  That isn't really a necessary thing anymore.
Instead make sure you are using the relevant SMART tools for your OS(es) to run tests and report results and failure signs before a catastrophic failure occurs.

If you want to format the drive for FAT32 then you can do that natively under a Windows system, or on Linux using the mkfs.vfat (or possibly mkfs.msdos) tools to format the filesystems. Of course make sure to partition the drive first - and use GPT style partitioning unless you have a compelling reason not to.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer please click the green check mark to accept it. Glad I could help!